Azure: Set an alert rule, that fires if a treshold was surpassed for 10 out of the last 30 days?
Question: How to set an alert rule, that fires if a treshold was surpassed for 10 out of the last 30 days?
Background: I have a query that looks if i have more node pools than reserved. The query and the result seems fine. (Query is a bit redundant, thats just for testing)
The query:
KubeNodeInventory
| where Computer startswith "aks-cpu" 
| where TimeGenerated >= startofday(ago(30d)) and TimeGenerated < startofday(now())  
| summarize AmtAboveReserved = dcount(Computer) by Day = bin(TimeGenerated, 1d)
| extend MoreThanReserved = AmtAboveReserved > 5
| extend AmountReserved = 5
| extend PodType = "aks-cpu"
| order by Day asc // until here build table to check results
| where AmtAboveReserved > 5 // here filter again for the alert rule

The result:

The alert rule:
I am a bit confused on how to set the alert rule correctly. I would like to fire the alert, if i filtered more than 10 rows. But that does not seem to work.

What i tried:

Using without "split by dimensions", that does not give a preview grafic in the "Create an alert rule" section and does not fire.
Setting the "Split by dimensions" as shown in the grafic, but that requires a specific numeric column -
Setting up a row counter: "| extend RowNumber = row_number()" and let the alarm fire on this column, but the value is shown as "2" and not 10 or 30.

